# Limit Console Output in Eclipse after a crash?

Tags: java, eclipse, heap-memory

I foolishly set the console in Eclipse to do unlimited buffering. I have a program that has been running for 10 days and now I am getting "IOConsoleUpdater has encountered a problem" and it mentions Java heap space. So I'm pretty sure it's the unlimited buffer size that is the problem.

I don't want to restart my program (I am doing a computation that takes weeks).  So short of restarting Eclipse, can I limit the Console output via a config file or something that will take effect immediately?  I can't do it through the GUI because the error windows won't go away (Specifically a dialog with heading "Internal Error" that wants me to close Eclipse). I believe the program is still running properly, so I think (hope) in the worst case that I just won't get the progress report anymore.

So, is there anything I can do?

Comment: After further reasearching it realize i was wrong. optimisation is always on in java anyway. But it seems you are out of luck if Eclipse got an exception and only prompt you to close then it's unrecoverable. Also, if your program runs for weeks. You should probably take the time to modify your program to take advantage of multithreading if possible(if you don't already) and maybe add some "safe-points" from which you could recover instead of starting from scratch. Because after all, you are never safe from a power failure.

Comment: I already made changes so that if I have to restart it I can continue from where it left off.  I was being optimistic when I started it and just hoping nothing would go wrong.  The program is highly threaded and running on a 24-core machine.